# Animating opacity in jQuery. Originally written in jsFiddle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have written code for a website in jsFiddle, but when I tried to port it over to Dreamweaver, my jQuery functions don't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("img.img").animate({
    opacity: 0.5
  });
});

$("#Musk").hover(function () {
  $("#Musk").animate({
    opacity: 1.0
  });
}, function () {
  $("#Musk").animate({
    opacity: 0.5
  });
});

$("#Branson").hover(function () {
  $("#Branson").animate({
    opacity: 1.0
  });
}, function () {
  $("#Branson").animate({
    opacity: 0.5
  });
});

$("#Lee").hover(function () {
  $("#Lee").animate({
    opacity: 1.0
  });
}, function () {
  $("#Lee").animate({
    opacity: 0.5
  });
});

$("#Tyson").hover(function () {
  $("#Tyson").animate({
    opacity: 1.0
  });
}, function () {
  $("#Tyson").animate({
    opacity: 0.5
  });
});

$("#Hadfield").hover(function () {
  $("#Hadfield").animate({
    opacity: 1.0
  });
}, function () {
  $("#Hadfield").animate({
    opacity: 0.5
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
  background-color: #00008B;
}
#header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
#p1 {
  font-family: helvetica;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#list {
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

    <script src="ØvingJS.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Øving6CSS.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <body>
      <h1 id="header">Inspirerende personer</h1>

      <p id="p1">For eksempelet har jeg valgt å droppe å inkludere kildene. Kildene kan dog finnes i bildebeskrivelsen img src: For eksempelet er også bildene justert på, eventuelt også blåst opp.</p>


      <ul id="list">

        <li>Elon Musk.</li>
        <img class="img" id="Musk" src="http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/5228cef96bb3f7b10c8b457c/youre-not-going-to-want-to-miss-elon-musk-at-ignition.jpg" width="50%" height="50%"/>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum Elon Musk</p>


        <li>Richard Branson.</li>
        <img class="img" id="Branson" src="http://www.lockhart-meyer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/richard-branson-600x452.jpg" width="50%" height="50%"/>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum Richard Branson</p>


        <li>Tim Berners Lee</li>
        <img class="img" id="Lee" src="http://www.boxmedianews.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/dd9e1394620451_111654883-600x335-250x200.jpg" width="50%" height="50%"/>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum Tim Berners Lee</p>


        <li>Neil deGrasse Tyson</li>
        <img class="img" id="Tyson" style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://krnb.com/sean-andre/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/06/neil-degrasse-tyson-600x349.jpg" width="50%" height="50%"/>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum Neil deGrasse Tyson</p>


        <li>Chris Hadfield</li>
        <img class="img" id="Hadfield" src="http://blog.hawkone.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/hadfield-600x403.jpg" width="50%" height="50%"/>

        <p>Lorem Ipsum Chris Hadfield</p>


      </ul>
    </body>
  </body>
</html>
```

The animate feature worked in jsFiddle when I used the jQuery version 2.x(edge) without any of the boxes checked and with the setting onLoad.

How would I be able to port the working file from jsFiddle over to a working version that would work on Dreamweaver?

Comment: Since it's working in JSfiddle and not in your local project you will have to do some troubleshooting. I'd start by making sure all the javascript files load properly. You can do this with Inspection Tools in most browsers.

Comment: What's this? `<script src="ØvingJS.js"></script>`?

Comment: "when I tried to port it over to Dreamweaver" - get a real IDE with real code control if you try to write real code. Dreamweaver is a WYSIWYG tool which is sort of *supposed* to break your code. Relying on it not to is optimistic to say the least.

Comment: All your jQuery hovers should be within the document ready. Also, why are you including jQuery twice?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, alternatively, he could just avoid using the Design View portion of Dreamweaver. Even then, I still prefer Sublime Text or Notepad++ or TextMate or Vim (and so on), but to each their own. What I'd be interested in is whether or not the only thing that breaks in the animation? Dreamweaver is terrible about using Windows line endings, so that could in theory be the culprit.

Comment: '<script src="ØvingJS.js"></script>' is the .js file I have my javaScript functions in.

Comment: Okay, @slimmey. Does it have any script, that might throw some errors and stop the other scripts from executing?

Comment: @PraveenKumar No. Not any other scripts than different tries of downloading and attaching 'query-2.1.1.js' or by using the 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it worked on load make it on load not on ready.

So from **$(document).ready(function ()** make it **$(window).load(function ()** and it will work :)

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("img.img").animate({
    opacity: 0.5
  });


  $("#Musk").hover(function() {
    $("#Musk").animate({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
  }, function() {
    $("#Musk").animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    });
  });

  $("#Branson").hover(function() {
    $("#Branson").animate({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
  }, function() {
    $("#Branson").animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    });
  });

  $("#Lee").hover(function() {
    $("#Lee").animate({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
  }, function() {
    $("#Lee").animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    });
  });

  $("#Tyson").hover(function() {
    $("#Tyson").animate({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
  }, function() {
    $("#Tyson").animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    });
  });

  $("#Hadfield").hover(function() {
    $("#Hadfield").animate({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
  }, function() {
    $("#Hadfield").animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  background-color: #00008B;
}
#header {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
#p1 {
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#list {
  font-family: helvetica;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="ØvingJS.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Øving6CSS.css">
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <h1 id="header">Inspirerende personer</h1>

    <p id="p1">For eksempelet har jeg valgt å droppe å inkludere kildene. Kildene kan dog finnes i bildebeskrivelsen img src: For eksempelet er også bildene justert på, eventuelt også blåst opp.</p>


    <ul id="list">

      <li>Elon Musk.</li>
      <img class="img" id="Musk" src="http://static3.businessinsider.com/image/5228cef96bb3f7b10c8b457c/youre-not-going-to-want-to-miss-elon-musk-at-ignition.jpg" width="50%" height="50%" />

      <p>Lorem Ipsum Elon Musk</p>


      <li>Richard Branson.</li>
      <img class="img" id="Branson" src="http://www.lockhart-meyer.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/richard-branson-600x452.jpg" width="50%" height="50%" />

      <p>Lorem Ipsum Richard Branson</p>


      <li>Tim Berners Lee</li>
      <img class="img" id="Lee" src="http://www.boxmedianews.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/dd9e1394620451_111654883-600x335-250x200.jpg" width="50%" height="50%" />

      <p>Lorem Ipsum Tim Berners Lee</p>


      <li>Neil deGrasse Tyson</li>
      <img class="img" id="Tyson" style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://krnb.com/sean-andre/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2014/06/neil-degrasse-tyson-600x349.jpg" width="50%" height="50%" />

      <p>Lorem Ipsum Neil deGrasse Tyson</p>


      <li>Chris Hadfield</li>
      <img class="img" id="Hadfield" src="http://blog.hawkone.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/hadfield-600x403.jpg" width="50%" height="50%" />

      <p>Lorem Ipsum Chris Hadfield</p>


    </ul>
  </body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there is nothing in the code that would be helped by binding to load. The problem is how the ready is not wrapping most of the methods

Comment: You should put all of the code inside the $(document).ready or $(window).load function to work properly :)

Comment: Thank you. It worked now with putting the code inside the `$(window.load)` function.

Answer (score 1):

I feel this might be an issue. Keep everything inside the `$(document).ready()` function. So, change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("img.img").animate({
    opacity: 0.5
  });


  $("#Musk").hover(function () {
    $("#Musk").animate({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
  }, function () {
    $("#Musk").animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    });
  });

  $("#Branson").hover(function () {
    $("#Branson").animate({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
  }, function () {
    $("#Branson").animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    });
  });

  $("#Lee").hover(function () {
    $("#Lee").animate({
      opacity: 1.0
    });
  }, function () {
    $("#Lee").animate({
      opacity: 0.5
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: Please specify what you changed. Just posting the code makes it really hard to see what you catually changed.

Comment: @NatalieHedström Thanks. Updated the answer. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a very powerful JavaScript library, but it seems as you are using a more complicated way of getting some cool effects on your hover states. This can very easily be accomplished with CSS3 try this:

```
#Lee{
    opacity: .5;
    -webkit-transition: all .32s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .32s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .32s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .32s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .32s ease-in-out;


}

#Lee:hover{
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: all .32s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .32s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .32s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .32s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .32s ease-in-out;

}
```

Comment: I always prefer using transitions but in some cases when you have to have support from IE9 and down you can't use transitions. there  is sadly still a lot of people using IE9.